# Problem with page flip animation when using WPF Book control

Tags: wpf, animation

I am using the WPF Book Control on [CodePlex](http://wpfbookcontrol.codeplex.com/) and found that the page flip animation sometimes jumps at the end. It tends to happen when you drag a page corner up and over or down and over to the opposite page. I have noticed that the animation ends when the corner hits the left/right edge of the book causing the page to jump to the final position. It does not happen when the corner follows the bottom edge (if dragging the bottom corner) or the top edge (when dragging the top corner) to the opposite page. I am hoping someone else has experienced this and has a solution or a different control.